# Is "in fiction" right?

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns, countability

> It is all very well for such things to occur in fiction.

Why not use **in fictions**?

Comment: It's referring to fiction as a category, not a specific individual work. Have you ever heard someone say "in fictions"?

Answer (score 0):

**Fiction** here refers to the general class of “all fiction”, not “all the books of fiction”.